# Any countries where there's a general speed limit for bicycles?

Tags: speed, legal

This not about e-bikes/e-bicycles or e-scooters, it's about the conventional human powered 2/3 wheeled vehicles, about the plain old bicycle.

I would like to know which countries (Europe mostly) have a speed limit for bicycles in their general traffic law (with article/reference or link if possible, language doesn't matter) for driving in built-up areas or not, on cycle paths or on the road.

Not interested in specific rules in a certain city/province but country wide rules and we all assume bicycles need to obey speed limit signs and regulations in cities, pedestrian zones etc.

All I know for now is **Spain** where the speed limit is 45 km/h built-up areas or not, but you can go faster if road circumstances allow a greater speed (and it's safe to do so I would add) - [Real Decreto 1428/2003 art 48](https://noticias.juridicas.com/base_datos/Admin/rd1428-2003.t2.html#cpa48):

> e) Para ciclos, ciclomotores de dos y tres ruedas y cuadriciclos ligeros: 45 kilómetros por hora. No obstante, los conductores de bicicletas podrán superar dicha velocidad máxima en aquellos tramos en los que las circunstancias de la vía permitan desarrollar una velocidad superior.

Comment: Related https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/564/can-you-be-ticketed-for-breaking-the-speed-limit-on-a-bike

Answer (score 5):

Many countries have some sort of road rule that says "drive to the conditions"  so you use common sense and best judgement, ie don't drive 100 km/h in fog just because that's what the posted sign says.

I'm not aware of any location in the world that legislates that bicycles must have a speedometer compulsory.

In the UK you can be charged with ***wanton and furious cycling***

> Laws that apply to motorists but NOT cyclists… 
> **Speeding offences** Because bikes aren’t fitted with speedometers, cyclists can’t be charged with speeding offences. HOWEVER, if they are considered to be going too fast for the conditions, they could be charges with ‘wanton or furious cycling’ which is a criminal offence under section 35 of the Offences Against the Persons Act 1861 (as amended by the Criminal Justice Act 1948 s1(2))

From https://www.roadlawbarristers.co.uk/wanton-and-furious-cycling-a-guide-to-the-road-traffic-laws-that-apply-to-cyclists/
(this is a short but interesting read too)